# Why does my for loop not work with an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I want the function to return a list of the indices where the values were equal in lst1 and lst2. When I run my code it only returns [0]. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image: [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsqHE.png)]

It should've returned [0, 2, 3]. I also tried adding an Else: continue, but that didn't help.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `[0]` because your counter `x` should be outside if condition.

```
def same_values(lst1,lst2):
    new=[]
    x=0
    for num in lst1:
        if num==lst2[x]:
            new.append(x)
        x=x+1
       
    return new
```

Alternatively, you can also get the indices by:

```
list1=[5,1,-10,3,3]
list2=[5,10,-10,3,5]

[index for index,value in enumerate(list1) if list2[index] == value]

#output
[0, 2, 3]
```